# What to return when you can't return a node in a linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have this simple `getNode()` function over here. Now, suppose the user calls for a node at an index that is greater than the length of the linked list itself. How can I handle such an error and return something?

```
NODE* getNode(NODE* start, int index)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        start = start -> next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: Typically, you'd just return `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you return `NULL`. Some libraries have function declarations like: `NODE *getNode(NODE *start, int index, int *status);` that sets a status code if there was an error.

You could do something like:

```
NODE *getNode(NODE *start, int index, int *status)
{
    // status of 1 means node not found
    *status = 1;
    // ...
    return NULL;
}

// ...

int status = 0;
NODE *myNode = getNode(nodeList, 10, &status);

if (!myNode && 1 == status) {
    printf("Not found!\n");
}
```